Can't record Microsoft Dynamics 365 FO for Jmeter Script
When I am trying to record jmeter scripts for Microsoft Dynamics 365 FO I am getting following error on just trying to load url in browser. Any idea on workarounds ?


java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte(GZIPInputStream.java:279)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUShort(GZIPInputStream.java:269)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:175)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:91)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.LaxGZIPInputStream.<init>(LaxGZIPInputStream.java:42)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.lambda$static$0(HTTPHC4Impl.java:205)
    at org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream.initWrapper(LazyDecompressingInputStream.java:51)
    at org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream.read(LazyDecompressingInputStream.java:63)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1950)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.readResponse(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:475)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:678)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1311)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:251)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.correlation.core.proxy.CorrelationProxy.run(CorrelationProxy.java:57)

i tried all browsers and also tried to use blazemeter plugin to record but no luck. Also i tried to record network in browser and converted HAR into JMX manually but no luck


If you're using Correlation Recorder Plugin - create an issue in the plugin's repository

If the error occurs with "normal" HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder - create an issue in JMeter repository


In general I don't think that any auto correlation tools support gzip/zstd/whatever compression method, you can try disabling compression by modifying your browser Accept-Encoding header somehow and once you done with recording you can add HTTP Header Manager with that header to re-enable compression for the script replay

Thanks for response. I tried all of these none of these seems to be working.
